# Prove by induction that $\Gamma \vdash \varphi \Rightarrow \Gamma[x/c] \vdash \varphi[x/c]$.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic, proof-explanation

As the title says: I want to prove by induction that $\Gamma \vdash \varphi \Rightarrow \Gamma[x/c] \vdash \varphi[x/c]$.

I’m struggling with how to write this proof. I think I need to do induction on the size of the derivation. The base case would be derivations of size 1, ie. $size(\mathcal{D}) = 1$. This, I imagine, would include $\vdash \varphi$ for tautological $\varphi$ and $\sigma \vdash \sigma$. This might not be right, but that’s not my biggest problem. I can’t figure out how to formulate an inductive hypothesis. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You are right. For the induction hypothesis assume that the property is true for any derivation of size less than $n$. Now take a derivation of size $n$, the first step of the derivation is something like $\Gamma_1\vdash \phi_1$ and $\Gamma_2 \vdash \phi_2$ gives that $\Gamma\vdash \phi$. Aplly the induction hypothesis on the derivation for $\phi_1$ and on the derivation for $\phi_2$ then using the same rule you should obtain a derivation for $\phi[x/c]$.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I don't quite see how I would show the substitution, though. Say I assume $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ holds for $size(\mathcal{D}) = n$, what do I need to show? I.e., what would a derivation of $\varphi[x/c]$ look like?